# CORS using ajax within PhoneGap+jQuery Mobile not working on device but is on browsers

Tags: iphone, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, cors

So I'm building an application using Phone Gap and jQuery mobile.

When using ajax to get a json response from a whitelisted server I am getting an error response. Nothing is showing in console however. The weird thing is that when testing the app within a web browser it works fine, it's only when I launch to my iphone device that it throws a strop.

It is worth saying now that the site I'm hosting my php scripts on is white listed within Phone Gap. I am using * in the array (just in case this makes a difference).
I have worked out a jsonp workaround for this but don't want to use it - I feel if it's working in browsers it must be possible on the device. I'm hoping it's a simple fix...

Here is my simple php script just echoing a json string.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Here is the JS

```
    $('#registerUser').submit(function() {
          $.ajax({
                 url: 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/path/register/add_user.php',
                 type: 'post',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 crossDomain : true,
                 timeout: 5000,
                 success: function(msg){
                    alert(msg.a);
                 },
                 error: function(){
                    alert('There was an error loading the data.');
                 }
                 });
          });
    });
```

edit: I also have this js on the page...it's recommended on the jquery mobile docs to use this when using Phone Gap

```
        <script>
        $( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {

            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
            $.support.cors = true;
        });

        </script>
```

And the form - I don't think this is necessary...

```
           <form id='registerUser' action="" method="POST">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
                    <label for="name">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""  />
                    <label for="name">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" value=""  />
                    <label for="name">Re-enter password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" value=""  />
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" aria-disabled="false">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Can you include the error message you are receiving?

Comment: The error message in the ajax function. Not a specific js error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it turns out there wasn't an issue with the code. It seemed that the app was cacheing the error result or something. I killed the app and relaunched it and all works fine now. From reading around it seems iOS6 safari caches POST which is different to previous versions.

I have added this in my ajax call to prevent caching the POST.

```
 headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
```

I hope this helps someone else as it has been a pain!

Thanks for the replies

Comment: I'm having the same problem, can you take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582456/why-firebug-network-and-console-results-are-different

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to try is augmenting your PHP server with the following:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

You will also need to make sure that your PHP server allows OPTIONS HTTP requests.

The longer answer is that the `dataType: 'json'` in your JS code is triggering a CORS preflight request. A preflight request basically asks the server for permission to make the actual request. You can learn more about CORS preflight here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Hey. I tried adding those extra headers and it hasn't worked. Still hitting the error statement in the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered cases where `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` was actually ignored by the client.  I believe the "proper" way (see [the w3c spec to confirm this](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)) to allow all domains via CORS is to actually grab the origin domain from the request header, then dynamically apply that origin to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header of the response, rather than using the wildcard character, to ensure that the client will respect the header.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

My experience with this issue proved to be caused by the fact that I was using httpS with an "invalid" SSL certificate. iPhone mobile safari and webview did not trust the SSL certificate and so did not make the AJAX request.

I was able to complete development by temporarily using plain HTTP.

My CORS headers were:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,Authorization
```