# Why Firebug Network and Console results are different

Tags: jquery, firefox, firebug, cors, http-post

This is the Network tab: See Image 1, at bottom.

This is the Console tab: See Image 2, at bottom.

So, How can this be ?
The results are from the same POST request.
Why does it says status 200, if it is an error ?
Why there is so much difference ?
Both of those request give me an empty response!, but if I try the request with [Postman, the REST client Extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) it returns a response !, see Image 3 at bottom.

To make the request, I´m using JQuery (and jQuery mobile). Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/rest/auth',
    data: {
        action : 'login',
        user_email: 'user',
        user_password:  'password',
    },
    type: 'post',                  
    async: 'true',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true,
    },
    crossDomain : true,
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
});
```

---

**Network:**
[image: Image Network]

---

**Console**
[image: Image Console]

---

**Postman  REST Client**
[image: enter code here]

---

Related questions:

1. [CORS using ajax within PhoneGap+jQuery Mobile not working on device but is on browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509084/cors-using-ajax-within-phonegapjquery-mobile-not-working-on-device-but-is-on-br)
2. ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-w?rq=1)

Comment: Are proper cors headers being returned? doesn't appear as so

Comment: @KevinB but why does the request from Postman does returns data ?, and can you name what headers are you talking about ?

Comment: I don't know what postman is, for all i know it could be ignoring the normal same-origin policy that ajax requests are bound by. Research CORS.

Comment: Yeah, I've been researching CORS.
is there a way, I can test my app (it's meant to be for PhoneGap) without using a browser ?

Comment: Did you try testing with Chrome? chrome gives a very clear error message when you run into CORS problems.